# how to know the version of windows app cert kit?

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I wanted to know the version of windows 8 app certification kit....
 
[image]

Comment: Latest version is 2.2 ...... Currently 2.1 is installed in my machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Location for version.ini
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\App Certification Kit\version.ini

Answer (score 0):

It's in the title bar when you run it :)  Type WindowKey+Q and search for "Cert" and "Windows App Cert Kit" will popup as option.

[image]

Comment: Mine is not showing here in the title bar, but i found it in programfiles.